# Cannot connect to localhost Google App Engine

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I recently upgraded from Google Cloud Endpoints v1 to v2 on Google App Engine. Before the update, my Android emulator could connect to the localhost instance of GAE (running with Eclipse), but now this error is shown when I try to access the local URL. Can anyone advise?

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /_ah/api/. Reason:

    Failed to retrieve API configs with status: 500
Caused by:

java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve API configs with status: 500
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.ApiServlet.getApiConfigSources(ApiServlet.java:104)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.ApiServlet.initConfigsIfNecessary(ApiServlet.java:69)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.RestApiServlet.service(RestApiServlet.java:114)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
```

My `pom.xml` has these two configs enabled, which I assume is related to connecting to localhost:

```
<address>0.0.0.0</address>
<port>8080</port>
```

In the Eclipse console, this error is also produced:

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: WARNING: /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs
[INFO] GCLOUD: java.lang.NullPointerException
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:100)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:71)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
```

Answer (score 0):

change your port address and you can also refer `127.0.0.1` loop back ip address or actual ip address if your connected with network,  instead `localhost`:

`LOCAL_APP_ENGINE_SERVER_URL_FOR_ANDROID` value to http://127.0.0.1:8888 (loop back ip address)

Added `--address=127.0.0.1` to run configuration program params . `--address=127.0.0.1 --port=8888` "/war"

Ran application, you can access administrate server using  `http://127.0.0.1:8888/_ah/admin/`

Comment: Where is this LOCAL_APP_ENGINE_SERVER_URL_FOR_ANDROID value that can be changed? Also you mentioned to add `--address...` to the run configuration program params, what is the Maven equivalent?